# How to send ListView data from one activity to another activity and then to another activity

Tags: android

I am very new to android, I am displaying ListView along with some data when I click my ListView whole data bundle and send data using intent ,this is working fine ,my doubt was when I send same data from 2nd activity to third activity only some fields only not all my data  ,

i am displaying after click my ListView filed using bundle but with this activity when i click image how to send current position string send to another activity 
any one please help me how to resolve that

Here my java code

```
 //movie image in reviews
    movie_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movieImage);

    //youtube image display id and imageView
    youtube_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movieyoutubeImg);
    youtube_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent youtube= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayYouTube1st.class);
            youtube.putExtra("youtubeLink",youtubeLink);
            startActivity(youtube);
           // Toast.makeText(Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.this,
                   // youtubeLink, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    });

   youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();


    Toast.makeText(Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.this,
            Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    mov_pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("mov_pos"));



    movie_title.setText(Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getNewTitle());


    rev_rating.setText(Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getReview());


    movie_description.setText(Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getNewDescription());
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load((Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos)).getNewsImage()).into(target);


    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load((Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos)).getNewsImage()).into(youtube_image);
```

Comment: It's a bit late but could you please clarify what you are trying to do? Your sentence starting with 'my doubt' isn't clear to me. Do you mean you're again sending everything but only some data is coming through?